# Angular js Custom Directive on element with ng-repeat - Can't set CSS classes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use a custom directive on an element with ng-repeat, like so:

```
<article ng-repeat="product in ctrl.products" class="product entity" 
    product="product" selected-retailer="ctrl.selectedRetailer"></article>
```

I've read that, in order for this to work, you need to set the priority on your custom directive to something higher than the ng-repeat directive. So I've defined my directive like so, setting the priority to 1001:

```
angular.module('MainApp')
    .directive('product', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                product: '=',
                selectedRetailer: '='
            },
            priority: 1001,
            templateUrl: '/Static/Templates/product.html',
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes) {
                $element.addClass('testCssClass');
            }
        };
    });
```

...and this works, it loops through my products.

The problem is, I'm also trying to set a CSS class on the directive's element (article) using:

```
$element.addClass('testCssClass');
```

...in the link function, but it doesn't seem to work.

But if I remove ng-repeat and just show first product item, like so:

```
<article class="product entity" product="ctrl.products[0]"
    selected-retailer="ctrl.selectedRetailer"></article>
```

...the CSS class shows up just fine (i.e. "product entity testCssClass").

How can I get this to work with ng-repeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was indeed a very unpleasant surprise form Angular.

You have to set **priority to -1001** for it to work. Reason: (from the docs of priority in the `$compile` service)

> #### Priority
>
> [...] Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first. [...] post-link functions are run in reverse order

From a small investigation ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8jus8h6/)) it seems that the `$element` passed to the `link` function is the *HTML comment* helper inserted by `ng-repeat`.